# oracle function to calculate week of date by considering Sunday to Saturday as a week

Tags: oracle

Hi we have requirement to determine week of date by considering "Sunday to Saturday" as one week but i went through the link [oracle function][1]

[1]: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php here there are options like 'IW'(week of year ISO standard) which calculates week of year by considering Monday to Sunday as one week but we have specs to consider "Sunday to Saturday" as one week.Can any one suggest how to calculate ?

Comment: Is this a question about Java or SQL?

Comment: I first thought at `TO_CHAR(mydate+1, 'IW')` as a quick and dirty hack -- but this is _probably_ wrong when the first/last day of year is on a week boundary.

Comment: "Accidentally" this (if wrapped into a function) works for 2015. `SELECT to_char( dateval, 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
      ,to_char( dateval, 'DAY') 
      ,round( rownum/7 )
 FROM 
    (SELECT (trunc(sysdate, 'YY') + rownum) -1 dateval FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY rownum < 366 )` Maybe it can give you a clue for making it better ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the "week number" you need basically two informations:

1. On which day does your week start? This you provided, week begins on Sunday
2. Which week do you consider as first week of the year? This you did
   not tell us.

The second definition may overrule the first one, e.g. "week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year." as used in Oracle `TO_CHAR(..., 'WW')`

Comment: if the First day of year is within Saturday then the week number of year/month is 1 else 2.Can you suggest how to calculate week number ?

Comment: Are you saying: "if January 1 is a Sunday, that's the first week, in all other cases, the first Sunday starts the second week".